# Java Spring error: Error creating Bean with name. Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, inject

I keep getting an error when compiling my web application. The error says: ' Could not autowire field: TaskService' etc.

I have the following setup:

The interface: TaskService

```
public interface TaskService { 
  String method1();
  String method2();
}
```

The Implementation of the interface: TaskServiceImpl

```
@Primary
@Service
public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

  @Inject MethodService methodService;
  @Inject ProviderService providerService;

  @Override
  public String method1(){
    return "X";
  }
  @Override
  public String method2(){
    return "Y";
  }
}
```

Then the controller using the service TaskService: TaskController

```
@Controller
public class TaskController(){

  @Inject TaskService taskService;

  @RequestMapping(value = {"/task"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getTask(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("task", taskService.method1());
    return "task.html";
}
```

With the setup described above i get the error HTTP Status 500. Servlet.init()
Error creating bean with name 'TaskController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; Could not autowire field: TaskService

If I remove the annotation @Controller from TaskController, then the program can start up. Does anybody have an idea why this is happening?

Comment: hmm are you sure Spring is scanning package where `TaskServiceImpl` is located for annotations?

Comment: Also, your TaskService also depends on methodService and providerService. Are those beans defined? what happens if you comment out the two lines?

Comment: Can you please provide your Spring configuration - e.g. how do you configure package scan for annotated classes? When you leave out @Controller the program likely starts because there is no Spring bean to initialize and so there is nothing to do.

Comment: Oh c'mon - full stacktrace or it didn't happen ;)

Comment: I wouldn't care about the stacktrace. I've seen this error when injecting so many times I can imagine what will be there. What I miss is the general Spring configuration which tells Spring where to look for `@Component`s so that he then picks them up and performs dependency injection.